# babel typescript operator overloading plugin

Tags: typescript, babeljs

i'm new to `babel` but i'm familiar with `typescript`, i found [this babel operator overloading example](https://github.com/rob-blackbourn/example-operator-overloading), but it's for `javascript`, i want to use operator overloading feature in my typescript project

i followed [this typescript babel starter project](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Babel-Starter) and tried to mix it with above operator overloading example project, but when i tried to build, the typescript compiler gives below errors:

```
> tsc --emitDeclarationOnly

src/index.ts:30:12 - error TS2365: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'import("/TypeScript-Babel-Overload/src/index").Point' and 'import("/TypeScript-Babel-Overload/src/index").Point'.

30 const p3 = p1 + p2
              ~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

my sample project on github: https://github.com/cjbd/TypeScript-Babel-Overload

how to make it work? please help, thank you!

---

update:

thanks to @Sly_cardinal, `@ts-ignore` works, the project complied throught, i've updated the github

question: can i ignore all the operator errors, globally? as i plan to use this a lot

thanks to @AlekseyL. , i forgot to enable the plugin below code is working now

```
'operator-overloading enabled'

class Point {

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
    }

    [Symbol.for('+')](other: Point) {
        const x = this.x + other.x
        const y = this.y + other.y
        return new Point(x, y)
    }

    x: number;
    y: number;
}

// Check overloads work
const p1 = new Point(5, 5)
const p2 = new Point(2, 3)
// @ts-ignore: operator overloading
const p3 = p1 + p2;
console.log(`p3 = (${p3.x}, ${p3.y})`)

$ node lib/index.js
p3 = (7, 8)
```

Comment: `'operator-overloading enabled'` ?

Comment: @AlekseyL. thanks a lot, yes, you're right, i didn't enable the plugin, now it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't allow operator overloading which is why you're getting that error.

Try using the `// @ts-ignore` comment to suppress the error on that line.

That should still let TypeScript emit your type definitions but allow babel to handle the transpilation to JavaScript. You might end up with weird, incomplete, or invalid type definitions though.

(See notes on how to use ts-ignore: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments)

You would need to use the ts-ignore comment anywhere you are using operator overloading or similar unsupported extensions to the JavaScript syntax.

Comment: thank you for your reply, it works!
btw, i'm planning to use a lot of this overloading feature, is there any way to ignore that error globally?